# selectpicker - show-subtext and data-live-search not working

Tags: jquery, select

I am trying to set data-live-search and showSubtext to "true" on selectpicker but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="create">Create subtext</option>
    <option value="update" data-subtext="old subtext">Update subtext</option>
    <option value="delete" data-subtext="more subtext">Delete subtext</option>
</select>

$(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
```

**[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/pvT8Q/202/)**  |  [selectpicker documentation](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: The bootstrap-select.js file is not found on your jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you sure? I am using this one: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/javascripts/bootstrap-select.js

Comment: I have a 404 for this link too.

Comment: arrrg stupid me! Yes the link was off that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Working now: http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/pvT8Q/203/

Comment: OK so I post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix the link of your bootstrap-select.js.